# Calculate residual column from groupby OLS

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, statsmodels

I am trying to calculate a residual column from groupby OLS statsmodels

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
import pandas as pd

df = sm.datasets.get_rdataset("Guerry", "HistData").data
vars = ['Department', 'Lottery', 'Literacy', 'Wealth', 'Region']
df = df[vars]
df = df.dropna()

def func_reg_residual(df, yvar, xvar):
    y = df[yvar].copy()
    x = df[xvar].copy()
    x['intercept'] = 1.
    mod = sm.OLS(y, x)
    res = mod.fit()
    yh  = mod.predict(res.params, x)
    err = y - yh
    return err

df.groupby('Region').apply(func_reg_residual, 'Lottery', ['Literacy', 'Wealth'] )
```

Everything is fine until the last line where residual are re-arranged by group and I cannot add this to my `df`. I could work around with merge, but I think that is not a good solution. I am looking for an efficient way to calculate it here

Comment: Not sure about the expected output here, but I think you're looking for `group_keys=False` parameter-value pair of `groupby`. You can refer to the documentation or try printing the output with/out it to see its effect. So, is `df["error"] = df.groupby('Region', group_keys=False).apply(func_reg_residual, 'Lottery', ['Literacy', 'Wealth'])` what you're looking for?

Comment: Thank you, you are right. Just add 'group_keys=False' actually solve the issue nicely. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You can perform the assignment for each group separately in `groupby`:

```
df.groupby('Region').apply(lambda g:g.assign(err = func_reg_residual(g, 'Lottery', ['Literacy', 'Wealth'] ))).reset_index(drop = True)
```

output

```
    Department      Lottery    Literacy    Wealth  Region          err
--  ------------  ---------  ----------  --------  --------  ---------
 0  Allier               66          13        61  C           5.85676
 1  Cantal               82          31        59  C          12.4498
 2  Cher                 44          13        63  C         -17.9569
 3  Correze              84          12        74  C          12.6914
 4  Creuse               85          23        78  C           3.20706
...
```